# jquery blockui with standard form submit (no Ajax)

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, struts-1

I'm using blockui with standard form post(java+struts1) no ajax or anything. It works great, but Im just wondering is this considered an ok thing to do. Basically all I wanted to do was lock
the browser screen upon submitting the form (when click on link) and show a message. I'm asking because it seems a lot of blockui examples use an ajax request.

My requirement is avoid user hitting multiple links on the page at a time. now as soon as clicking on one link blocking the page with this blockui (https://github.com/malsup/blockui/) until the process finishes and load the page with new data.

--------------- updated ----------------

I did 2 steps:
dowloaded the 'jquery.blockui.min.js' from https://github.com/malsup/blockui/ and added this js file in my workspace
added below code snippet in my jsp

```
$('#linkX').click(function() { 
$.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="busy.gif" /> Just a moment...</h1>' }); 
});
```

now when i click on any links (all links has same class name) the page blocks with popup message "jest a moment". since i have form action in the jsp as `<html:form action="/xxx.do">` it perfomrs the process backside and enter some data in the database (until that process completed few seconds main page blocks with this popup message which i needed to control the user hitting another link which interupts the 1st link process), and it loads the page back (with new data). Automatically on page load this unblocks the ui.

this blockui perfectly fulfilling my requirement. But every where this blockui getting used with Ajax calls not with regular form submit so i wonder whether it can be also used with regualr form submit too or not? (or if there is any other simple solution to block the ui as Im not using Ajax)and is this dowloaded blockui javascript file is safe to use (as Im working for the federal company)?

Comment: A request is a request; if the goal is to stop additional interaction and wait until the page reloads, sure, it's fine. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Since Im newbie to Jqery I want make sure Im using it correctly or not. I dowloaded 'jquery.blockui.min.js' from https://github.com/malsup/blockui/ and added this JS file in my workspace, and next added below small code snippet to my jsp. $('#linkX').click(function() { 
$.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="busy.gif" /> Just a moment...</h1>' });
}); This is working fine for what I needed to block the UI but is this blockUI can be used for regular form submit without ajax call? @Dave Newton: as you said, looks like it cab used for regular form submit not necessarily with Ajax call only, right?

Comment: You can tell if you're using it correctly by seeing if it works. Unrelated, but if you have a code-related question, put the code in the question, not in comments; it's impossible to read there. BlockUI just blocks the UI; it doesn't care *why* it's being used.

Comment: @Dave Newton, I have updated the post with code snippet.

Comment: My point is that if does what you need it to, then it works.

Comment: @Dave Newton: kool thanks Dave, I will stick to this solution. (Since im very new to Jquery i was little concerned to use it with regular form submit as it was never mentioned anywhere) you are right as it is working i should not worry. Just quick question, do i need to add a code/line to unblock the ui? right now when page loads it automatically unblocks ui.

Comment: When the redirect happens your page is "starting over". Although again--if it does what you need it to, over time, then chances are it's working. Have confidence in your observations (and occasionally back them up with empirical evidence).

Comment: thanks Dave for your prompt replies :)